# If $|A|\leq|B|$, then $|\mathscr{P}(A)|\leq|\mathscr{P}(B)|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $|A|\leq|B|$, then $|\mathscr{P}(A)|\leq|\mathscr{P}(B)|$.

I know that $|A|\leq|B|$ implies that there is an injection $f:A\to B$. I also know that for any set $S$, $|S|<|\mathscr{P}(S)|$.

Clearly I need to show that there is also an injection from $\mathscr{P}(A)$ to $\mathscr{P}(B)$ but I'm really struggling to think of a way to get there.

I'm not asking for a solution but if anybody has a small hint to point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: For each subset of $S\subset A$ what can you say about $f(S)$?

Comment: @JohnDouma Could you elaborate a bit more? Certainly for each subset of $S\subset A$, we have $S\in\mathscr{P}(A)$ but I don't think that's what you mean..

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Each subset of $A$ therefore corresponds to a subset of $B$ so...?

Answer (score -3):

It is enough to Know that $|\mathscr{P}(A)|=2^{|A|}$ so $$ |\mathscr{P}(A)|=2^{|A|}\leq 2^{|B|}=|\mathscr{P}(B)|$$ It remains to show  $$ |\mathscr{P}(A)|=2^{|A|}$$
define a bijection function $$f\colon \mathscr{P}(A)\to 2^{A}$$ by $f(C)=\chi_{C}$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of $C$, that is , $\chi_{C} (x)=1$ for $x\in C$ and $\chi_{C} (x)=0$   for $x\in A\setminus C.$ I hope it is clear now

Comment: This question is equivalent to the implication $|A| \leq |B| \Rightarrow 2^{|A|} \leq 2^{|B|}$.. (p.s. I did not downvote)

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ are infinite though?

Comment: @Gteal, I did not see any problem with infinity

Comment: @guidoar, he was asking for hint

Comment: @00GB  don't assume all users with non-revealing usernames represent "he".

Comment: Yes, but this hint is literally equivalent to the question; even the OP has more information since it goes from the definitions to the existence of some injections. I deleted my hint because it's already in the comments

Comment: @MiloBrandt, I have $2^{|A|}\leq 2^{|B|}$ Not $2^A\leq 2^B$